# Force R to display the output rounded with 3 digits

Tags: r

I using R with Rstudio. I want to change the default behavior of R,preferably via options(), to show the numeric results of the output (ie, the values printed in the console) rounded with 3 decimal digits.

I know that I can use
`round( x, digits = 3)` command, but my objective is to compare "by eye" several variables, and enclosing all variables with the "round" (or "format") command is cumbersome.

An example of what I want:
I want to the command `matrix(c(0.00003,0.1111111),ncol=1)` give the output:

```
        [,1] 
   [1,] 0.000
   [2,] 0.111
```

I try to use `options(digits=3)`, but with that command, some results are displayed in scientific notation. I also try `options(digits=3, scipen = 999)` but the scipen argument makes the R to print more decimal places in the output.

Ps.: I want to change only the output, not the variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R actually tries to help you here but showing the default number of digits, and offers different ways to influence this as you saw.

However, sometimes we want to override this in a 'brute force way'.  One possible way is to `round()`:

```
> matrix(c(0.00003,0.1111111),ncol=1)   # your example
         [,1]
[1,] 0.000030
[2,] 0.111111
>
> round(matrix(c(0.00003,0.1111111),ncol=1), digits=3)
      [,1]
[1,] 0.000
[2,] 0.111
>
```

If you want to automate this you could create a new type `myMatrix` which inherits from `matrix`, and overwrites its `print` method by one that rounds as shown here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to avoid the method of putting the array inside a round function because of all the typing I have to do. About the suggestion of using a new type: is it possible to replace the matrix printing method globally and then go back?

Comment: If you do not do anything else the _global_ `print.matrix()` gets called so you would have to change that --- but most people would consider that a bad design.  I would write a simple custom `print()` routine.  Your call.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach to define a new class with a different print method :

```
library(stringr)
options(myMatDigit = 3)

print.myMat <- function(mat)
{
  myMatDigits <- getOption("myMatDigit")
  nb_Col <- ncol(mat)
  nb_Row <- nrow(mat)

  for(i in 1 : nb_Col)
  {
    mat_Char[, i] <- round(mat[, i], digits = myMatDigits)
  }
  
  print(mat_Char)
}

mat <- matrix(c(0.00003, 0.1111111), ncol = 1)
mat <- structure(mat, class = "myMat")

mat

     [,1]
[1,] 0.000
[2,] 0.111
```

With this approach, you can set a global option with myMatDigit that you can use in the class afterwards.